# expression must have class type and pushing a class

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
class Hex{

    public:
        void setSize();
        inline int getSize() const{return size;};
        inline int getType() const{return type;};
        void fillCells();
        void setType();
        void disp() const;
    private:
        class Cell{
            Hex::Cell();
            Hex::Cell(int gx,int gy,char gcell = celltype::empty);
            private :
                int x,y;
                char cell;
            public :
                void setCoordinate(int gx,int gy);
                void setCoordinate();
                //inline void showCoordinate(){ cout << x << "," << y;};  
                inline char getCell() const{return cell;};

        };
        vector< vector<Cell> > hexCells;
        int size, type;
};

Hex::Cell::Cell() : cell(celltype::empty), x(-1), y(-1){};

void  Hex::fillCells(){

    Cell den();
    vector<Cell> row;
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<size; ++j){
          den.setCoordinate(i,j);     
          row.push_back(den);     
        }
        hexCells.push_back(row);
   }
```

When i try to declare a Cell (private nested class)object  in fillCell it gives me error

```
expression must have a class type
```

Why is this happening? How can i fix it?

Comment: Don't write `Cell den();`, instead use `Cell den;`. The first one defines a function, not a `Cell` object. Your compiler should have warned about this. I'm not 100% sure if this solves your issue, but start by fixing this.

Comment: Yeah,It works thank you but normally as I known if define a constructor like Cell();  we could not create object Cell den; how could it happend here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: expression must have a class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007898/error-expression-must-have-a-class-type)

Comment: Also see [tag:most-vexing-parse].