# C++ doesn't recognize my class as a class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am stuck on this and I am sure it is something obvious that I just don't see. I have been staring at the code too long or something. Compiler generates this error:

```
[build] /home/chrisk/Projects/TMH/US26064/H1T_Apps/src/impact_manager/tst/unit/impact_data_error_test.cc:451:11: error: request for member ‘GetMaxCount’ in ‘impact_manager::Teid155’, which is of non-class type ‘impact_manager::TelematicsErrorOneShot(nxex::Client, uint32_t, ErrorSourceE, ErrorStatusE, ErrorSeverity)’ {aka ‘impact_manager::TelematicsErrorOneShot(nxex::detail::Client<>, unsigned int, ErrorSourceE, ErrorStatusE, ErrorSeverity)’}
[build]   451 |   Teid155.GetMaxCount();
[build]       |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know that the compiler's complaint is that I am using a "." on an entity that the compiler doesn't think is a class.

I am trying to figure out why the compiler doesn't think Teid155 is a class. When I hover over the Teid155 in VScode it shows the following:

```
expression must have class type but it has type "impact_manager::TelematicsErrorOneShot (*)(nxex::Client client, uint32_t ExcessiveImpactsWarning, ErrorSourceE ES_LINUX, ErrorStatusE EVENT, ErrorSeverity ESV_WARNING)"C/C++(153)
```

The offending code where I am instantiating the object looks like this:

```
 TelematicsErrorOneShot Teid155(
    nxex::Client client, 
    uint32_t ExcessiveImpactsWarning, 
    ErrorSourceE ES_LINUX, 
    ErrorStatusE EVENT, 
    ErrorSeverity ESV_WARNING);

  Teid155.GetMaxCount();
```

The include file that declares the class is:

```
namespace impact_manager {

class TelematicsErrorOneShot : public TelematicsErrorOneShotInterface {
 public:
  TelematicsErrorOneShot(nxex::Client& client, uint32_t teid, ErrorSourceE source, ErrorStatusE status, ErrorSeverityE severity);
<more stuff defining the other functions>
```

The interface is it is based off of looks  like this:

```
namespace impact_manager {

class TelematicsErrorOneShotInterface {
 public:
  /**
   * @brief TelematicsErrorOneShotInterface destructor.
   */
  virtual ~TelematicsErrorOneShotInterface() = default;
<more stuff showing other functions>
```

And the .cc file where it gets defined looks like this:

```
namespace impact_manager {

TelematicsErrorOneShot::TelematicsErrorOneShot(
    nxex::Client& client,
    uint32_t teid,
    ErrorSourceE source,
    ErrorStatusE status, 
    ErrorSeverityE severity)
    : client_(client),
    teid_(teid),
    source_(source),
    status_(status),
    severity_(severity) {}
<bunch more stuff defining functions in the class>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: *"I know that the compiler's complaint is that I am using a '.' on an entity that the compiler doesn't think is a class."* -- Not quite. If it was a class (e.g. `TelematicsErrorOneShot`), it would still be an error. The syntax is for **objects** of a class (which your identifier is not). To be more precise, the compiler thinks `Teid155` is a function, and the dot-syntax is not valid for functions.

Comment: `Teid155` is a function.  If you intended for it to be an object, you need to remove the types from its parameters, i.e. `TelematicsErrorOneShot Teid155(client, ExcessiveImpactsWarning, ES_LINUX, EVENT, ESV_WARNING);`.

Comment: To help you read the error message: compare `non-class type ‘impact_manager::TelematicsErrorOneShot(nxex::Client, uint32_t, ErrorSourceE, ErrorStatusE, ErrorSeverity)’` to `class type ‘impact_manager::TelematicsErrorOneShot’`. The former is what the compiler sees, and the latter is what you seem to think you have.

Comment: The question might not be an exact duplicate, but this answer applies: [A: error: expression must have a class type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969535)

Comment: Side note  you might want to pass `nxex::Client` by const reference so it will not be copied unecessary

Answer (score 0):

*If you intended for it to be an object, you need to remove the types from its parameters,*

Thank you. I knew it was something I was staring at and just couldn't see.

```
  TelematicsErrorOneShot Teid155(client, ExcessiveImpactsWarning, ES_LINUX, EVENT, ESV_WARNING);

  Teid155.GetMaxCount();
```

That change above works fine.

Comment: With the types you created a function declaration Teid155() which returns a TelematicsErrorOneShot;